# How to configure Selenium Grid in docker-compose.yml (max session)

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I couldn't find how to configure the Selenium Grid with Docker Compose.

How can I set for example the `maxSessions` in the `docker-compose.yml` for ***a Node***?

I tried the following without success:

```
 selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    networks:
      - mynet
    environment:
      - MAX_SESSION=4 // DOES NOT WORK
      - maxSession=4 // DOES NOT WORK
    hostname: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    networks:
      - mynet
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
      - MAX_SESSION=4 // DOES NOT WORK
      - maxSession=4 // DOES NOT WORK
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add this `ENV` under `chrome`:

```
NODE_MAX_SESSION=4 # As integer, maps to "maxSession"
```

read from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#increasing-the-number-of-browser-instancesslots)

Comment: thanks that helped to find the correct answer: `- NODE_MAX_SESSION=5` in `chrome`. I couldn't find the reference though - if you can adjust your answer - I will accept it.

Comment: but it is still the same?! Not NODE_MAX_SESSION=5 in chrome

Comment: sorry I thought you just need it for the grid not node, I did now Ihope :)